# Fast plotting of large amount of rectangles with pyqtgraph

Tags: python, plot, rectangles, pyqtgraph

**Background**: need to plot a large amount of rectangles (can be ~10 million of them) interactively.

found out about [pyqtgraph](https://www.pyqtgraph.org/) and tried the following:

```py
class Visualizer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = pg.mkQApp()
        self.pw = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.pw.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.vb = self.pw.getViewBox()
        self.vb.setAspectLocked()

    @staticmethod
    def _bbox2coords(bbox):
        # dividing by 1e6 for normalization
        return pygeos.get_coordinates(pygeos.box(*bbox.bounds2d())) / 1e6

    def plot(self, elements: list):
        self.pw.addItem(
            MultiRectPlot(
                map(Visualizer._bbox2coords,[e.bbox() for e in elements])
            )
        )
        self.pw.show()
        self.app.exec()
```

while the MultiRectPlot is:

```py
class MultiRectPlot(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, data, pen='w', brush=None):
        super().__init__(None)
        self.setCacheMode(1)
        self.pen = pen
        self.brush = brush
        self.data = data
        self.rects = [self.get_rect_points(rect) for rect in self.data]
        self.picture = QtGui.QPicture()
        self.generate_picture()

    @staticmethod
    def get_rect_points(rect):
        xmin = rect[:, 0].min()
        xmax = rect[:, 0].max()
        ymin = rect[:, 1:].min()
        ymax = rect[:, 1:].max()
        return xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax

    def generate_picture(self):
        p = QtGui.QPainter(self.picture)
        p.setPen(pg.mkPen(self.pen))
        if self.brush:
            p.setBrush(self.brush)
        for rect in self.rects:
            self.xmin, self.ymin, self.xmax, self.ymax = rect
            p.drawRect(self.boundingRect())
        p.end()

    def paint(self, p, *args):
        p.drawPicture(0, 0, self.picture)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QtCore.QRectF(self.xmin, self.ymin, self.xmax - self.xmin, self.ymax - self.ymin)
```

Anyway, the plot itself showing up pretty quick, but the following are very slow:

1. Zooming (in and out)
2. Moving around the plot

I do want to make it as quick (smooth) as possible, even if it says to reduce the number of rectangles while I'm zoomed-out and show more details when I'm zooming in (like lazy loading?)

Hope someone can help here :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for
[datashader](https://datashader.org/index.html)?

It uses a dynamic aggregation based on the dpi and figure-size and can plot ridiculous amounts of data in no time :-)

Comment: Tried datashader!
It is great for plotting but I need to expand my usage and make the rectangles clickable and add some GUI features.. it seems like it won't help me with that!

Comment: ... that is not entirely true... but the implementation might be a bit more involved... if you use [datashader with matplotlib](https://datashader.org/getting_started/Interactivity.html#native-support-for-matplotlib) you can customize [object picking](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/event_handling.html#object-picking) as you like...    (I did a similar thing in [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps) to make very large geographical datasets "pickable" while being visualized with datashader  (... and matplotlib can be embedded in qt or wx guis)